# Virtual Box fix CPU performance

Tags: virtualbox

Is there a way to fix Virtual Box CPU resources? I want to conduct comparative performance tests and want to be sure that Virtual Box process will not consume all my free system CPU power? So basically, for example, can I allocate , 1GHz with 2 cores?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Settings window for a VirtualBox guest, you can go to System/Motherboard and set the amount of RAM. You can't say "1GHz", but you can set an Execution Cap (% of available processing resources) and number of Processors in System/Processor. AIR, the recommendation is to use as few processors as possible for the VM. You can change these settings while the guest is shut down.